# jqueryでスムーズスクロールを実装、idにピュニコード混じりの文字列を使うとエラーがでる

Tags: jquery

jqueryを使ったスムーズスクロールを実装しています。
以下のコードです。

```js
$(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function () {
        var speed = 400;
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        var target = $(href == "#" || href == "" ? 'html' : href);
        var position = target.offset().top;
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: position }, speed, "swing");
        return false;
    });
});
```

htmlファイルはこのようにします。

```
<a href="#no_%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e">h2へ</a>
<h2 id="no_%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e">ここにいく</h2>
```

移動はできるのですが、javascriptでエラーがでてスムーズスクロールになりません。

エラーは以下のとおりです。

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #no_%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e
```

このようにピュニコード混じりのidではスムーズスクロールができないのでしょうか。
解決策があれば教えて下さい。

Answer (score 1):

> 移動はできるのですが、javascriptでエラーがでてスムーズスクロールになりません。
>   このようにピュニコード混じりのidではスムーズスクロールができないのでしょうか。
>   解決策があれば教えて下さい。

URI の 仕様としては '#no_%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e' (#no_日本語 の UTF8 表現) は
問題ないでしょうが、
HTML の タグに % エンコードされたID 指定は正しくないのではないでしょうか？

ID を 日本語 で記入 、 URL は urlエンコードして指定。

```
<a href="#no_%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e">h2へ</a>
<h2 id="no_日本語">ここにいく</h2>
```

JavaScript では url デコードして ID を検索

```
var href = decodeURI($(this).attr("href"));
```

にしたら、chrome でも Edge でも 動作する事が確認できました。

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございました。無事に動かすことができました。